# Windows Phone 8.1 ListView and MenuFlyout

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I have a problem displaying a MenuFlyout on a ListViewItem.
I searched the web and all the examples I found are almost the same (attach the MenuFlyout in xaml and open it in a Holding event).

The menu works but the problem is the ListView. 
If I hold the "mouse" on a listview item the menu appears but if I don't release the "mouse" I'm able to scroll the listview with the MenuFlyout visible.

How can I prevent the listview to scroll in this situation?

Example code:
Xaml:

```
<Grid>
  <ListView Name="ListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Holding="Grid_Holding">
          <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
            <MenuFlyout>
              <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" />
              <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Refresh" />
              <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Share" />
            </MenuFlyout>
          </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="24" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  List<string> strings = new List<string>();
  Random rnd = new Random();
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
      sb.Append((char)rnd.Next(97, 122));
    }
    strings.Add(sb.ToString());
  }
  ListView.ItemsSource = strings;
}

private void Grid_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  FrameworkElement senderElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
  FlyoutBase flyoutBase = FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(senderElement);

  flyoutBase.ShowAt(senderElement);
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Came along the same problem. MSDN support told it is a known bug and will be fixed with the next SDK update...

Comment: Many thanks. :) Do you have a link to a official MS forum or bugtracker?

Comment: Was chat support. Don't know if an official bug list is even provided (found a lot of them in listview especially...)